# JavaScript math not adding up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with my math function below. The `depreciationFee` variable adds up correctly, but for some odd reason the `financeFee` variable does not. I am trying to calculate the monthly lease payment of a vehicle. Whenever I submit the numbers for `financeFee` it shows two number appended to each other rather than added together. Is there a reason the numbers aren't adding up correctly?

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {

  function calculateLease() {

    var capitalCost = $(".capital-cost").val();
    var downPayment = $(".down-payment").val();
    var residualCost = $(".residual-cost").val();
    var monthTerm = $(".month-term").val();
    var moneyFactor = $(".money-factor").val();

    var depreciationFee = (((capitalCost - downPayment) - residualCost) / monthTerm);

    // THIS IS THE ONE THAT DOESN'T WORK
    var financeFee = ((capitalCost - downPayment) + residualCost);

    alert(financeFee);

  }

  calculateLease();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lease-calculator-container">
  <h3>LEASE CALCULATOR</h3>
  <form method="get">
    <input type="text" class="capital-cost" placeholder="MSRP" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="down-payment" placeholder="DOWN PAYMENT" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="residual-cost" placeholder="RESIDUAL" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="month-term" placeholder="TERM IN MONTHS" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="money-factor" placeholder="MONEY FACTOR" />
    <br />
  </form>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="CALCULATE" />
  <div class="monthly-cost"></div>
  <div class="total-cost"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, what units are you working in and what is the smallest unit you need to be correct to?

Comment: Convert your strings to numbers.

Comment: Try to use parseInt(myValue, 10) or float, to convert explicitly

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery adding 2 numbers from input fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269385/jquery-adding-2-numbers-from-input-fields)

Comment: Lets say:

capital cost = 25000
down Payment = 5000
residual cost = 5000

output = 200005000

It doesn't actually add them together like it should

Comment: Have you read the comments and links? The answers are there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269385/jquery-adding-2-numbers-from-input-fields

Comment: Division is an operation that cannot be performed on strings and is the final operation in the first equation. As a result the first equation forces conversion to Number. The second does a subtraction which works properly on Numbers. Then it adds it to the string `residualCost` converting the entire thing to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `parseInt(value,10)` for intergers or `parseFloat(value)` for float.

JavaScript appends the values if the data type is not a number.

Comment: Whenever recommending parseInt I think it's important to explain that the second parameter is a radix to indicate it's base 10. If you leave it off, bad things may happen.